# SparkR: Assign values of a column with condition

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to replace values of a column with a certain condition.

Example of R data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:7),value=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "c"))
```

I want to replace values "c" and "d", in column value by "e".

In R, it can be done this way

```
df[df$value %in% c("c","d"),]$value <- "e"
```

I tried to do the same thing in sparkR. Tried `ifelse`, `when` functions but couldn't give me the desired result.

Does anyway run into the same issue?

Comment: `df$value <- ifelse(df$value %in% c("c","d"), "e", df$value)` should equally work on `Spark DataFrame`'s.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got an error `Error in rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'environment'`

Comment: What spark version are u running?

Comment: I am running spark 1.6

Comment: I think this was a known bug, fixed in 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

The first comment of mtoto works well (with spark 3.0.1) and should be transformed in answer and accepted.

```
df$value <- ifelse(df$value %in% c("c","d"), "e", df$value)
```

Another valid slightly different method to replace strings in a column could be the following:

```
df$value <- regexp_replace(df$value, "c", "e")
```